# WS2812 high inrush current in big installation

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, inrush-current, ws2812b

I have a "big" installation with WS2813 (WS2812b successor) LEDs. The installation encompasses over 350 LEDs which should consume about 21A if all powered on, which should never happen (it's a simply dimm and sparse art installation). The display objects must be connected by cables at lest 2m long.

When I start up the supply or connect enough LEDs, the PSU goes into OC protection and shuts down. When I connect just a few the PSU keeps up and now LEDs re light in this instance.

I'm now suspecting either the LEDs to draw enough current at startup or the long cables having enough capacitance to trip the OC protection. Unfortunately I don't have access to an oscilloscope to check the short startup current...

I was thinking about reducing the inrush current to the supply lines.I'm only an amateur-level tinkerer. My ideas were resistors, NTCs or inductors, but a resistor would be an obvious bad choice, an NTC wouldn't stay low resistance if not a lot of current is drawn (am I right?).

Now I'm thinking about an inductor, but do recall reading about it being a bad choice for that, but am not really sure.

Do you have experience with supplying large numbers of LEDs and did you ever encounter any issues like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1 (declined in the comments as doesn't solve the inrush problem):

Get an arduino or alike; something that can run the FastLED library or some similar library; then the coding is trivial. Within the code you can set a timer so that the led strips are turned on in sequence instead of all togheter. Or, maybe even better, you can start the program allocating a small led array, and reallocating the led array a few times, each time with more leds, in order to turn them on in sequence...

You must do some math in advance because both the memory and timings are constraints; ie: with FastLED every led uses 3 bytes of memory, so the controller must have at least leds*3 bytes of memory. About timings: depends on how efficient is your code and how fast is the cpu, as the controller must refresh the command to all leds within some time constraints. Currently I'm using an arduino nano v3 to control 214 leds; but for 350 you probably must get something a bit more beefy (ex: atmega1280 in the arduino uno, instead of the atmega328 on the arduino nano).

Option2:

If you can't change the controller because you need complex color commands, you can place a simple ne555+relay circuit every few leds. The ne555 can be set to 'start counting' at power on (ie: when the previous strip turns on), and once the count ends... fire the relay to turn on the next strip. At the end of the next strip you can place another ne555+relay... and so on. ne555 and relays are pretty common, you can probably find them easy in your local electronic parts store.
Just cascade strip->timer->strip->timer->strip... up to 3m/1024 LEDS, or the maximum amps the pcb can carry. After that you'll need to combine more cables, more controllers, more whatever.

I wrote NE555 because in electronics it is The Venerable Timer Lord, but you can use anything you want, having a timer. I've never used a NE555 in production myself, because I prefer to supply attiny85 to optimize my parts storage. I've half a dozen of the low power NE555 version, "just in case" I need something that uses less power than the (ridicolous already) attiny85 power need. But I've never used one of those. If you have sone arduino unos around, and size isn't a problem... can go with those! An STM chip, a zilog z80, anything with a timer is fine :)
Just consider the NE555 can be driven with 5v as well as 12v. In the case of an arduino (atmega) instead, you can choose between 3V3 and 5V versions, so you might need to step-down the voltage for the arduino to work...

About the relay: you need a relay having the command rail voltage same of the LEDs voltage (5v or 12v?). And a main rail amperage big enough (12A? 20A?). You may also need a transistor as the NE555 (or other uC) by itself can't supply enough current to trigger the relay command. The NE555 have more than 200mA Iout, the atmegas 20-25mA... so, hooking the transistor base to NE555 might be needed. It depends from the relay you can get.

For the exact circuit you'd better search a bit; I'm pretty sure you can easily find the circuit you need, because the NE555 is ... everywhere, since ever. The God Of Timers. It has been used everywhere in the world and outer space, since before the piramyds.
Or just make a new question and hopefully someone will link a good one.

**EDIT:** updated to include comments.

Comment: I don't have any issues coding. I would use an Arduino library or something if I wouldn't be able to write it myself. I only need to write some RGB values, I don't need the overhead of their animation code.

Comment: And in the end you didn't get my point. I'm not surprised about a huge current spike when I try to turn on all LEDs. I'm having the issue when connecting the strip / powering up way before any color is sent. To test this I actually uploaded an empty sketch and I still get the power-up current spike which is the aspect that gets me wondering

Comment: The power supply should be able to handle all LEDs constantly on with no problem by the way. It's a 20A jobby and I have a theoretical current max of ~12A (I'm testing with only one half of the installation, so 175 LEDs)

Comment: That's normal. On connect all leds flash, then go black waiting for command. That's why I wrote the second option (ne555+relay). Do a test: use 50 leds and see if it works. Then, keeping the first 50 on, add 50 more, and so on up to the 175. If it works, it's just a matter of inrush current and you can solve with ne555+relay.

Comment: Strange, when I add less enough, I don't see them flash. I actually use the WS2813, which are the successor of the 2812. Maybe they changed that or it is so quick, that I can't really make it out. A sequenced start is absolutely a viable option.

Comment: I need to check if I can segment the installation and run a multi-core cable with thinner wires, but I won't be able to accomplish it in time. It's a bit sad, I had hoped there could be a simpler solution. But if there is really no way around, I have to bite the bullet and use the installation for a different occasion

Comment: HOLD ON! You don't need multicore wires! The control wires (command and backup) and GND, are the same, you don't need to cut them. You need to cut only the positive one every n leds to stuff a ne555+relay in between. Everything else stays. I don't have experience with WS2813, as mine are a cheaper version of those named GS8208 (they run colder, brighter and use a bit less current). But they work the same, mine are chinese clones. And it works. My 214 LEDs are cut in two parts of different sizes and I'm using an ATX PSU to turn them on, probably a bit beefier PSU but ... your has 20A, still big

Comment: Yes sure! Thanks ;) The installation object should be connected by a single cable, so I'd need multiple conductors from the sequenced power supply and then distribute them as you said inside the thing. And data would be a single wire of cause

Comment: Ahahaha, no dude. Probably I didn't write clearly but... again... you don't need multiple cores! You can cascade the strips and timer circuit! Strip->timer->strip->timer->strip... The only reason to need more wires is in the case the amount of LEDs (so the amount of current) is too much for the LEDs pcb.

Comment: Hahah Oh darn it! Now I got it. Pretty neat idea! thanks :D

Comment: Would you maybe rewrite your answer to focus on this aspect with a little bit more clear description? I'd totally accept it then

Comment: I can't find any information about the maximum pcb current because the LED datasheet isn't the STRIP datasheet. On the LED datasheet they say 3m max lenght and 1024+ LEDS, for timing, but can't say anything about the PCB because the strips are assembled by other companies...

Comment: Yeah, I already split the supply inside the object to reduce the voltage drop. As I read it should be fine. Then the cascaded power up delay and I should be good to go

Comment: The answer is edited. I don't have a circuit handy, and can't search by now. But if you open another question let me know, maybe tonight or tomorrow I'll give it a go.

Comment: Oh yeah, having 2 positive wires makes your life easier, because you don't need 20A relays (hard to find). The most common (and cheap) ones are 10A. Consider that every relay must be able to handle all the current after itself... so... 2 wires, means that the total 12A can be split into 2*6. ie: less than the single relay maximum.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the PSU power-on ramp, that would be your best bet. Also, check to see if the LEDs can be convinced to power up in an all-off state.

You could also split up your LED array into multiple power domains and use additional supplies. If you’re on a tight timeline this may be your go-to solution, which you know can work.

Comment: As well as searching for a solution, I'm really confused. The LEDs do power on in an all-off state or a few are on a low level. The PSU can supply over 20A so I'm maximum confused why I should have such a big spike... The ramp isn't controllable unfortunately. I'll try to throw even more power at it, but I'm not sure I can rig up something that big quickly

Comment: Thanks for the input, will keep my gears working. I'll update if I get any closer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are holding the data line low during power-up. If you are controlling by a micro then you may be picking up noise from somewhere and this may send a valid data code to the LEDs until the microcontroller powers up, initialises, configures the data line as an output (rather than a floating tri-state) and pulls the line to a defined logic level.

I would imagine a 10 kΩ resistor between DATA and GND would do the trick (if this is the problem).

Comment: I tried this on my LEDs and doesn't work. The leds flash as you connect the 12v line even when data line is connected to GND. Mine aren't WS2813 (are GS8208), but are defined as WS2813 clones.

Comment: Already tried that, thanks. It might be just the accumulated startup current. Maybe the PSUs OCP is sensitive to spikes... I unfortunately can't measure it properly at the moment. I'll try a different PSU and some other ideas, but I'm not in a rush anymore.